# Using tiles in SFML and collision detection

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml, tile

I decided to look a good tileset to use and found some, but the question is how I actually load the tile from the image file as there seem to be more than one tile in one file?

Also how do I implement a collision detection for non square tiles?

Example: [Tileset](http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs44/f/2009/159/1/6/Pokemon_Platinum_Tiles_WIP_by_klnothincomin.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images(sfml1.6) or Textures (sfml2.0) are usually drawn using `sf::Sprite`.
The usual way to do it is to let all sprites share the same tileset texture/image, and then use `sf::Sprite::SetSubRect(const IntRect &SubRect)` to set the area of the texture that should be drawn.

The Sprite class in the sfml API is probably a good place to start

- http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Sprite.php
- http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Sprite.php