# SFML collision detection only working at the origin?

Tags: c++, sfml

I was wondering why my collision only works when I move my sprite to the origin of the screen. Is it a problem with the way I loaded my map or is there something about how sprites work that I don't fully understand? Here is my code for the tilemap

Tilemap.cpp

```
#include "Tilemap.h"
#include "Player.h"

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

//default constructor
Tilemap::Tilemap()
{
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("map/purpleBlock.png"))
    {
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    }

    sprite.setTexture(texture);
}

//reads tilemap from a text file into an array
void Tilemap::loadTile(RenderWindow &window, string filename)
{
    string temp;
    ifstream mapFile;
    mapFile.open("map/test.map");

    if (!mapFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error opening " << filename << endl;
    }

    //getline(mapFile, tileSet);

    //reading height, width, tile height, tile width and storing them into variables
    getline(mapFile, temp);
    tileWidth = stoi(temp, nullptr);
    getline(mapFile, temp);
    tileHeight = stoi(temp, nullptr);

    getline(mapFile, temp);
    width = stoi(temp, nullptr);
    getline(mapFile, temp);
    height = stoi(temp, nullptr);

    data = new int[width*height];

    //reading values into array
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            char temp;
            mapFile >> data[x + y * width] >> temp;
        }
    }

    mapFile.close();
}

//drawing the map onto the screen
void Tilemap::drawMap(RenderWindow &window)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            if (!data[x + y * width] == 0)
            {
                sprite.setPosition(x * 32, y * 32);
                sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight));
                window.draw(sprite);
            }
        }
    }

}

//testing collision
bool Tilemap::tileCollision(RenderWindow &window, RectangleShape &rect)
{
    if (sprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects(rect.getGlobalBounds()))
    {
        cout << "Collision" << endl;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one sprite and you change its position to draw it. Okay, but when you test if there is a collision, you test the collision with lastest position you set to your sprite. So, you should not test collision with your sprite. If you still can access to your map, use it instead.

EDIT:

i saw your post [Using tiles in SFML and collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321812/using-tiles-in-sfml-and-collision-detection?rq=1)

The sf::Texture is the resource, sf::Sprite is just a class to draw, so you can create many sprites with few textures. (`std::vector<std::vector<sf::Sprite>> map`)